# Handling alerts using if/else in Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

How to handle the **alerts** using **if/else** commands? If alerts comes up do **accept/dismiss**, if not **proceed further**. I was trying with below code but an error at **(r==true)** says incompatible type.

```
bool r = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'javax.baja.sys.ActionInvokeException')]"));
if (r = true) {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
} else {
    Actions click2 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement dclick2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Bluemix_As_Device']"));
    click2.moveToElement(dclick2).doubleClick().build().perform();
}
```

Comment: `=` is the [assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html). `==` is the [equality operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). Additionally...`bool` isn't a keyword in Java. Does this code actually compile?

Comment: @nbrooks that seems a typo, the text says `r==true` but the code reads `r=true` and the error is for incompatible types. Not editing that part, relying on OP to update the typo.

Comment: @nullpointer The code is incorrect, despite what the description in the question states. Both of the errors I mention are things that the compiler would have reported. Either we're not looking at the OP's actual code, or the OP hasn't attempted to compile this or shared the errors with us. Either way, this question has a few issues.

Comment: *this question has a few issues.* Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

The incompatible type is for the reason that

```
driver.findElement
```

would return a [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) type and not a `boolean`(that's java). You might want to change the code to:

```
try {
    WebElement r = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'javax.baja.sys.ActionInvokeException')]"));
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); // this would be executed only if above element is found
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
    // since the element was not found, I 'm still doing some stuff
    Actions click2 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement dclick2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Bluemix_As_Device']"));
    click2.moveToElement(dclick2).doubleClick().build().perform();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, this code works fine in case of alert comes up however it fails when the alert doesn't appear. In my application the alert pop is not consistently appears for the same operation. So I would like to handle such a way that when the alert appear then either accept/dismiss the alert and if alert doesn't appear at all then skip to next line of code without failure. I am not sure how to handle this could be if/else command?

Comment: @Abhi not really if/else, you can catch `Exception` as generic if you're getting any other exception thrown probably.

Answer (score 0):

As r is of boolean type so there is no need to write if(r == true) or if(r == false) you can directly write if(r) and java will understand the code.

Comment: Based on your suggestion i tried                                                               
**bool r= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'javax.baja.sys.ActionInvokeException')]"));
    if (r) {** but still facing same issue.

Comment: There is no need to write if(r=true) you should write if(r) only as r is of boolean type. Or you can also write if(r == true)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElements will check the existence of the object and will return 1 if exist else zero.
So in your case though the alert exist or not, it will handle and based on size it will execute next step. Hope this helps in your case.

int r= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'javax.baja.sys.ActionInvokeException')]")).size();
if(r!=0){
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
} else {
    Actions click2 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement dclick2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Bluemix_As_Device']"));
    click2.moveToElement(dclick2).doubleClick().build().perform();
}
```